# Grails redirect breaks params types

Tags: grails, grails-controller

My Grails code has a search function that redirects to another controller action after performing a findAllBy query:

```
def results = Foo.findAllByBar(baz)
redirect(action: "result", params: [results: results])
```

findAllByBar returns an ArrayList with models, as expected, but after the redirect the receiving action gets a String array. Worse, when there is only one result it doesn't even get an array, it just gets a String.

Given that I have to iterate through the results in the receiving view, doing it on a string will meticulously print every letter individually. We can all agree that that's probably not the ideal behaviour.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A redirect results in a new GET request with the parameters in the querystring, e.g. /controller/result?foo=bar&baz=123 - you can't put objects there since it's just a string.

You could put the ids of the objects in the params and load them in the `result` action:

```
def action1 = {
   def results = Foo.findAllByBar(baz)
   redirect(action: "result", params: [resultIds: results.id.join(',')])
}

def result = {
   def resultIds = params.resultIds.split(',')*.toLong()
   def results = Foo.getAll(resultIds)
}
```

or put them in Flash scope:

```
def action1 = {
   flash.results = Foo.findAllByBar(baz)
   redirect(action: "result")
}

def result = {
   def results = flash.results
}
```

Comment: That would make sense - I assumed redirects within the same controller were delegated within the same request.

Comment: Use [forward](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/forward.html) for that

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use the chain method instead of the redirect method. Chain lets you pass a model as a parameter similar to render.
An example would be:

```
chain(action:'result',model:[results:results])
```

Heres a link for further information:
http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/chain.html

Comment: nice... didn't know about `chain`.  Any downsides of using it? vs. a redirect?